# merge textbox values with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 5 textbox in html. I want to merge their values. All of them have one name. How can I do it?

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" name="textbox1">
<input type="text" name="textbox1">
```

Comment: Make separate ID's for them. Using Dom get the text and merge them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the values as an array, and join it

```
var val = [].map.call( document.getElementsByName('textbox1'), (el) => el.value ).join('');
```

```js
var values = [].map.call( document.getElementsByName('textbox1'), (el) => el.value ).join('');

console.log(values)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="a1-">
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="a2-">
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="a3-">
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="a4-">
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="a5-">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select by the `name` attribute of your inputs, use [`getElementsByName`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("textbox1");
var inputValues = "";
for(var index=0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
    inputValues += inputs[index].value;
}
```